# Display custom archetype properties in Intellij "create project from archetype" wizard

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, maven-archetype

I have a custom maven archetype to define an internal company project structure.
This archetype has some required additional properties. E.g.,**system-code**

```
<archetype-descriptor>
    <requiredProperties>        
        <requiredProperty key="system-code"/>
        ...
    </requiredProperties>
    ...
</archetype-descriptor>
```

If I run the artifact through the command line:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=... -DarchetypeArtifactId=... -DarchetypeVersion=...
```

The custom property is requested so the user doesn't need to know that this property exsists before running the mvn archetype:generate plugin.

```
$ Define value for property 'system-code':
```

What I want to do is something similar when I create a new project from the archetype in Intellij-idea. Following the advices of other SO questions, I've created an [artifact-catalog](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-catalog/archetype-catalog.html) and added the plugin [maven artifacts catalog](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7965-maven-archetype-catalogs) to Idea. So far all is working fine and I can create a new project from the archetype.

[image]

However, in the archetype properties dialog, there is no trace of the custom property **system-code**, and in some use cases the user doesn't have to know this property is required.

[image]

If I go ahead creating the project, I expected that maybe the system-code property would be requested in the command line, but that's not the case and the property creation fails precisely because the system-code property is missing.

```
[ERROR] Property system-code is missing.
```

If in the properties dialog I manually add the **system-code** property, all works as expected, but as I said, I think is something not easy to know for the user.

So, the question is if anyone knows if is it posible to display the archetype custom properties somehow in the Intellij-idea new project creation wizard?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support it at the moment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81665.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CrazyCoder! It seems to be that I didn't google enough before asking the question :) If you want to add the comment as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, IntelliJ IDEA [doesn't support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81665) it at the moment, you can [watch/vote](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) the issue in YouTrack.

Comment: Thanks, voted and watched. I think it's a common use case for those we work with custom archetypes. Woud it be really nice to have it fixed.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't implemented yet! I even tried the below answer of adding the property during the creation, and I see it in the command line that gets executed as `-DmyProperty=Something` but it still doesn't recognize it during the creating, just says `[WARNING] Property 'myProperty' was not specified`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property manually during the creation using the wizard.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3

[Make sure the required property is indicated in the archetype-metadata.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3shF.png)

In the screen that lists the properties, you can hit the plus symbol to add a Maven Property, Match the name listed in the archetype-metadata.xml file and add the value of this property

[Properties screen and add maven proerty popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRWWL.png)

Clicking OK will add this property to the list and the project will build using the custom property as designed.

I hope this helps

Comment: re-reading your question, I see that you already knew that this could be added manually. I will leave my response however to help anyone else use this workaround until IntelliJ IDEA adds this functionality